# Spark partitionBy equivalent in Flink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm looking to write streaming data into separate folders based on partitions by key, like `partitionBy` in Spark.

Data:

```
key1 1
key2 1
key1 2
key3 1
...
```

Expected output:

```
/output_directory/key1
+-- part-0-0
+-- part-0-1
+-- ...
/output_directory/key2
+-- part-0-0
+-- part-0-1
+-- ...
/output_directory/key3
+-- part-0-0
+-- part-0-1
+-- ...
...
```

(I read about stream splitting and custom sinks in Flink. But it seems that the former is not suited to cases where the keys are not known in advance. As for custom sinks - I would like to see if there are other ways out before looking into them.)

Are there built-in methods or third-party libraries to achieve this in Flink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Flink's [FileSink](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/api/java/org/apache/flink/connector/file/sink/FileSink.html), which you will want to use with a [BucketAssigner](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/sink/filesystem/BucketAssigner.html) that assigns stream elements to buckets based on their key.

For more details, see https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/connectors/datastream/file_sink/.

Comment: Will take a look. Thank you very much!